# How can i draw in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

So im currently coding a snake game , and i need to draw the first pixel that indicates the head of the snake (positioned in the middle of the software). But i can't seem to find any function that does drawing on the screen . I've tried using DrawRectang and DrawPixel.

Any help ples?

Comment: You may want to start looking here: [https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__class__gdi.html](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__class__gdi.html) the description ***The following are classes related to GDI (Graphics Device Interface) access.

They provide an API for drawing on device contexts, windows, and printing.*** seems to be what you want.

Comment: ***I've tried using DrawRectang and DrawPixel*** if you show your code someone can help you to fix it. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets has capabilities to custom draw a widget/window (or a small invalidated part of one) through it's own drawing API.

This is usually used for customized buttons or other controls, graphs, etc. You can handle `EVT_PAINT` ([`wxPaintEvent`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_paint_event.html)) where you can create a DC ("Device Context"). As well as on creation or size changes, you can force a redraw with [`wxWindow::Refresh`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_window.html#a29dc7251746154c821b17841b9877830) or [`wxWindow::RefreshRect`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_window.html#ab0ae6b9898cd261c39ebeb2891aa3d67) (for a small part). You might do so using a timer.

Note that the performance and capability is fairly limited. You can use OpenGL or Direct3D , or various high level libraries with wxWidgets, the native platform window handle is obtainable through [`wxWindow::GetHandle`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a185e6cd7065367b552748cb722651b27).

Comment: Thank you so much , i think i am finally progressing with the program . Didn't think you needed an event handler to draw as well whew

Comment: I guess because most GUI's are based on very limited hardware power and not wasting battery, even when you have like a scrollbar with loads of content, much of it off-screen due to scrollbars other windows being "on top". Usually in a GUI (especially older ones back when this was designed, and resources were such every window/application on the screen might share a **single "bitmap"**) very little changes frame to frame, so the system just needs to draw bits and pieces. Sometimes not even because of your own program, e.g. if another window was dragged over above it overwriting the shared image